# Is $\cos(90 - 2x) = \sin (2x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

What does $\cos(90 - 2x)$ equal? I know $\cos (90 - x) = \sin x$ but does this equal $\sin 2x$?
Thanks.

Comment: it's in degrees

Comment: @user108716, put $x=2y$

Comment: Can you use the difference formula here? http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html $(\cos (u - v))$

Comment: cos(90-x) does not equal sin(x). cos(π/2-x) on the other hand, does.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee then you get cos$(90-4y)$. If you put $2x=y$ then you get cos$(90-y)$ which equals sin$(y)$

Answer (score 2):

In $\cos(90−x)=\sin(x)$ the $x$ can work for *any* number, which implies $2x$ can work as well.

Comment: cheers for the answer